# how to use streamwriter and file append in Windows phone8.1?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-async

In windows phone 8.1
i want to use streamwriter in text, and appending text to file end.
But the text is appended to the beginning of the file.
how to appending text to file end?

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///input_category_list.txt"));
using (StreamWriter sWrite = new StreamWriter(await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(), System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8))
{  
    sWrite.WriteLine(write_category_box.Text);
    await sWrite.FlushAsync();                        
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for `StreamWriter` in Windows Runtime, you can use `FileIO` class (which is easier):

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///input_category_list.txt"));

await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, write_category_box.Text, UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this:

```
new StreamWriter(await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(),System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8,true))
```

if you overrride `StreamWriter` constructor, as `true`, this will set to append text. Otherwise overwrite it.